# Why are there no sophisticated construction animations in RTS games in general?

Tags: animation, rts

I want to code a small demo to test what degree of detail regarding animations, is possible in modern RTS/building games and which of them have the largest impact on the playing experience. Similar to the first few minutes of a '0 A.D'/AoE game. (No music and art assets, no story, *as simple as possible*.)

All building animations in RTS and building games are made rather modest. They simply arise from the ground or jump from one state of completion to the next accompanied by some particle effects.
The Settler games are the only ones known to me, that **model the transportation of goods to the building lot and make the area plane, before they build on it**.

*In the demo I mainly want to focus on the construction process, that should be continuous. **The building material is to be represented by objects in the game world.** Based on a predetermined pattern, workers shall combine these building materials piece by piece to a building.*

**Had one of you the same idea and experienced difficulties, that led them to the adoption to a simpler animation/building scheme?** Are there computational problems, because this approach needs to many calculations (e.g. for collision detection of the building blocks)?

---

List of different ways construction has been done in RTS / building games before:

*Positions of interest are stored in the links.*

- **Sprite fades in:**
- - [Settlers 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=vF6HszKcuB4#t=221)
- **Completed building emerges at desired location:**
- - [Anno 1404](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=YsQDxtylpMQ#t=16), Anno 2070, (haven't checked the early ones)
- - Stronghold, [Stronghold Crusader 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Q9cKLjVujVk#t=30) (and 1)
- **Building arises from ground** (without or with worker units bashing the ground)
- - [0 A.D.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=db9hi9g2240#t=72)
- - [Godus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=M5ANTGzxLZo#t=27)
- - [Dawn of War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=LJee-D29iNA#t=5) (with extra animation, while the building is ascending)
- **Incremental, stepping animation** (without or with moving/non-moving worker units):
- - [Age of Empires 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2uYRG4PlsLo#t=85)
- - [Age of Empires 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=q8lAl30hs5w#t=124)
- **Incremental, continuous animation** (without or with moving/non-moving worker units):
- - ?
- - [WarCraft 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbE4oRKW1wc) (a mixture of different animation types)
- - StarCraft 2 (similar to WarCraft)

Comment: In games like StarCraft one would probably not notice the detail, but games like Settlers, Stronghold and 0 A.D. if not played with 'maniacs' could gain strongly from a more detailed construction process. These are not depending that strongly on an extremely fast gameplay, but enable the player to focus on the building process a lot more than the war.

I don't think, that answering the question is opinion based. _Maybe I should rephrase the question, so it becomes clear, that I am asking for technical difficulties or time consumption._

Comment: That would still be pretty broad and discussion oriented. What *actual* problem are you trying to solve in your own game?

Comment: I think your best bet here is to try it and see how it works. Nearly all of the problems with this would be project specific, related to implementation or design preferences. All of which are different for each project. We can't know if you're going to have trouble with it.

Comment: Conquest: Frontier Wars had a few of the traits that you describe, although it's based in space rather than on a planet surface. Ships and stations would be built continuously - you'd see the ship gradually take form from girders and struts (although these items did not appear in the world before being added to the ship). It also had a simplified concept of supply lines, which would prevent construction in areas cut off from resources. http://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/62936-conquest-frontier-wars-windows-screenshot-major-construction.jpg